# Problem with getting header on title page in document class acmart

Tags: header-footer, acmart

when i compile my project the header appears on every page but the very first one - the title one. here is my code

```
\documentclass[a4paper, sigconf]{acmart}

\usepackage{adjustbox,lipsum}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

% Copyright
%\setcopyright{none}
\setcopyright{acmcopyright}
%\setcopyright{acmlicensed}
%\setcopyright{rightsretained}
%\setcopyright{usgov}
%\setcopyright{usgovmixed}
%\setcopyright{cagov}
%\setcopyright{cagovmixed}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\lhead{Late-Breaking Results, Demonstration and Theory, Opinion \& Reflection Paper}
\rhead{UMAP'17, July 9-12, 2017, Bratislava, Slovakia}
\cfoot{\thepage}
\settopmatter{printacmref=false}

\acmConference[UMAP'17]{Adjunct, July 09-12}{Adjunct, July 09-12, 2017}{Bratislava, Slovakia}
\acmISBN{978-1-4503-5067-9/17/07}

\acmDOI{10.1145/3099023.3099063}

\begin{document}
bla bla
```

Comment: your example isn't complete so doesn't show the issue, but it is normal for title pages, chapter openings etc to use `\thispagestyle{plain}` so not have the heading. `fancyhdr` has commands to redefine the plain style to have headings if you wish

Comment: the solution was to add \thispagestyle{fancy} after \maketitle

Answer (score 1):

If you're not using `\maketitle`, you can add

```
\AtBeginDocument{\thispagestyle{fancy}}
```

to your preamble to have the `fancy` page style applied to the first page. It's typical for the first page to have a `plain` page style.

If you are using `\maketitle`, you can add

```
\let\oldmaketitle\maketitle
\renewcommand{\maketitle}{%
  \oldmaketitle%
  \thispagestyle{fancy}}
```

to your preamble, which will insert the `fancy` page style *after* calling `\maketitle`, correcting again the use of the (traditional) `plain` page style associated with a title page.